# Java ClassLoader Basics

Tags: java, abstract-class, classloader

I have a need for a personal command-line tool that should take the name of a concrete subclass as a CL argument and instantiate the correct Java class at runtime:

```
public class MyCommandLineTool
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        // Read the name of the desired class to load
        String strClassName = getClassNameFromArgs(args);

        // Now create an instance of that class (if it exists/is valid/etc.)
        Shape oShape = someMagicalClassLoaderCall(strClassName);

        // Now call the subclass's overridden draw() method
        oShape.draw();
    }
}

public abstract class Shape
{
    // Some stuff

    public abstract void draw();
}

public class Circle extends Shape
{
    @Override
    public void draw()
    {
        // etc...
    }
}
```

Therefore, from the command line, you might run the program as follows:

```
java MyCommandLineTool -shape Circle
```

Or something like that (not worried about the syntax of the command line call right now).

I've read several introductory tutorials on ClassLoaders, but am choking on understanding *when* one needs to write their own class loader.  All the tutorials seem to focus on *how* to write your class loader, but without explaining when it is appropriate to do so. And, because it seems fairly complicated to do this, I would prefer to not have to write my own if I don't have to.

It seems to me that if I have a compiled `Circle.class` file, any JVM should have no problem reading that class file and constructing an instance of a `Circle` at runtime based on a string I pass it containing that class's name.

Can anyone clarify whether or not I need to write my own loader for this specific example, why, and if not, what I need to implement in lieu of `someMagicalClassLoaderCall(String)`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll have to make sure that the actual class is on the classpath when you run your program

```
Class clazz = Class.forName("fully.qualyfied.ClassName");
Shape instance = (Shape)clazz.newInstance();
instance.draw()
```

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't need to write your own class loader for that - just specify the classpath correctly.  Something like this should work:

```
String className = 'Circle';
Class myClass = Class.forName(className);
Object ofMyClass = myClass.newInstance();
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be as easy as:

```
Class c = Class.forName(strClassName);
Object o = c.newInstance();
```